# Run two commands in parallel with docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, makefile, celery

Im trying to execute two instances of celery in background within a docker container.

The command im using is this in a makefile:

```
.PHONY: ciwie_run
ciwie_run:
    $(COMPOSE_FILE) run --rm scraper.api celery -A ciwie.app worker --loglevel=INFO -Q backtest-request.fifo &
    $(COMPOSE_FILE) run --rm scraper.api celery -A ciwie.app worker --loglevel=INFO -Q backtest-request-high-priority.fifo &
```

But the output im receiving is this:

```
[+] Creating 1/0
[+] Creating 1/0
 ✔ Container scraper_service-redis-1  Running                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 ✔ Container scraper_service-redis-1  Running                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
the input device is not a TTY
the input device is not a TTY
```

My command does not include -it flag, which i already tried adding too and didnt work. I expect it to run both commands in parallel and output logs.

The full command being executed is the following:

```
DOCKER_USER=bordin docker-compose run --rm scraper.api celery -A ciwie.app worker --loglevel=INFO -Q backtest-request.fifo &
DOCKER_USER=bordin docker-compose run --rm scraper.api celery -A ciwie.app worker --loglevel=INFO -Q backtest-request-high-priority.fifo &
```

Comment: Long-running processes like a Celery worker are probably better declared in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  `docker-compose run` is better for short-lived commands that are expected to exit.